# How to prevent automated request?

Tags: php, security

I was wondering how to set up a system in which an authenticated user could send, with a simple graphical interaction (cliccking a button or so) a non-replayable request/message to the server from an application or a web page.
It's crytical there's must not be a way to set up an automated system that replaces user interaction automating the request as this would totally break up my entire project.
Moreover, as this action must be frequently repeated, it should not implement boring stuff like chaptas or so.

A pratical example: let's say the web page, shown after the login, displays a button that sends the server a request. How can I be sure the request was sent because the user actually clicked the button and it wasn't some sort of bot that forged the message?

Is that even possible to check? I'm sure it is and I'm quite sure there's must be some simple implementation I'm missing, and I'm sorry if this is a trivial question.
Also, if the solution is hiding ('cause I already searched a lot!) out there, please point me to it.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Capture mouse moving in javascript?

Comment: Anything that is based on user interaction can be scripted with JS in a way that will be indistinguishable from an actual user. Your best bet is a captcha .... sorry.

Comment: If you want only humans, the input has to include something only humans can provide. Captchas are usually the way to go. Actually, that's *why* captchas were invented.

Comment: BTW, captchas are only needed on the first input of a session. After that you know you've got a human, so skip the captcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a non-graphical captcha like a simple question.
Generate a simple addition of two random integers between 0 and 10.
Add a text field to ask for the result.
The result is very easy to find (for a human being), and very quick to type.

**Example**:
What is the result of 7+5? Write your result here: [*_*]

It should only block robots and very young or very stupid people.

Comment: Duplicate request is also a request. What if I use loop and hit 1 million request to the server? How to prevent that request?